# Using SBT with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, sbt

I am trying to use sbt in eclipse with a small project. I have downloaded the sbt msi. Installed it. Added
 `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")`
in plugins.sbt in the `home\.sbt\0.13\plugins` directory

Also added the SBT_HOME environmental variable and added the sbt to the PATH variable. I can run the sbt command and the dependencies get downloaded to `home\.ivy2\cache` directory.

The project has numerous not found errors as the jars are not found. The jars are in the above mentioned directory and not in the project directory. While this is understandable for many projects using the same jars, I cannot see where the link is between the .ivy2 location and the project. sbteclipse is also in the `home\.ivy2` directory. So running eclipse command in the project directory gives unresolved errors for the sbteclipse jar

This is the first time I am using sbt. Please help me out as this is the fourth day I am struggling with this..

Comment: anyone?? I really need help ...

Comment: I went to the home\.sbt\ path and ran the sbt eclipse command.The .project , .classpath and the target folder I just copied to my project dir. Now there are no errors. But obviously this is not the right way. Someone please point me in the right direction...I went to the home\.sbt\ path and ran the sbt eclipse command.The .project , .classpath and the target folder I just copied to my project dir. Now there are no errors. But obviously this is not the right way. Someone please point me in the right direction...